# Binary Plane Partition: do we have to split a line segment?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm considering the planar [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) problem, where we are required to partition a set of disjoint line segments in the plane, such that every region in the partition contains at most one line segment or a portion of one line segment.

My question is: is there a way of partition these line segments such that no line segment is split into more than one region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "No". Please see a counterexample below:
[image: 3Segments]